# Passing an struct to a Post martini routine

Tags: data-binding, go, martini

I have an issue using this statement

```
  m.Post(Model, binding.Form(Wish), func(wish Wish, r render.Render, db *mgo.Database) {
```

This worked fine if I use the struct define inside the prog like

```
  m.Post(Model, binding.Form(Wish1{}) , func(wish Wish1, r render.Render, db     *mgo.Database) {
```

but I need this to be an independent package. 
I get "Wish is not a type" wish is the return of the binding function. 
This worked with a primary Type struct. I am passing the strut as a interface{}

I am using GO with Martini.Classic() It is really complicated for me to change Martini or Binding package.  Any suggestions.

This is the all code

```
package chlistpkg
import (
  "github.com/codegangsta/martini"
  "github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/binding"
  "github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/render"
  "labix.org/v2/mgo"
  "time"
  "fmt"
  "html/template"
  "reflect"
  "adminStruct"
)
```

just to show the struct  that I need to pass as to routine Doall

```
type Wish1 struct {
  Name        string `form:"name"`
  Description string `form:"description"`
  AnyDate     time.Time  `form:"anydate"`
  Active      bool   `form:"active"`
  Number      int    `form:"number"`
  NumDec      float32  `form:"numDec"`
 }
```

DB Returns a martini.Handler

```
 func DB() martini.Handler {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://localhost")
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
     }

 return func(c martini.Context) {
    s := session.Clone()
    c.Map(s.DB("advent2"))
    defer s.Close()
    c.Next()
}
```

}

GetAll returns all Wishes in the database

```
 func GetAll(db *mgo.Database, entList interface{}) interface{} {
   db.C("wishes").Find(nil).All(entList)
   fmt.Println("GettAll entList =", entList)
   return entList
 }


   func Doall(Model string, Wish interface{}, Wish2 interface{}, Wishlist interface{}         ) {
     m := martini.Classic()
     fmt.Println ("martini.Classic =", m)
     m.Use(martini.Static("images")) // serve from the "images" directory as well

     m.Use(render.Renderer(render.Options{
        Directory: "templates",
        Layout: "layout",
      }))

   m.Use(DB())

   m.Get(Model, func(r render.Render, db *mgo.Database) {
     r.HTML(200, "lista4", GetAll(db,  Wishlist))
   })
```

binding does not take a pointer. I have to pass the struct by reference on "Wish"
the issue is the return on    "wish Wish"   I got an error Wish is not a type
at compilation time

```
m.Post(Model, binding.Form(Wish), func(wish Wish, r render.Render, db *mgo.Database) {
fmt.Println("Input wish =", wish)
db.C("wishes").Insert(wish)
r.HTML(200, "lista4", GetAll(db, Wishlist))
})

m.Run()
```

Thanks in advance

Luis

Comment: Can you post the line(s) the error refers to? There's a lot going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is that you have called your type `Wish1` (with a numerical 1) but you are referring to the `Wish` type (which does not exist!) in your code.

Change your struct to be:

```
// Note: "Wish", not "Wish1"
type Wish struct {
  Name        string `form:"name"`
  Description string `form:"description"`
  AnyDate     time.Time  `form:"anydate"`
  Active      bool   `form:"active"`
  Number      int    `form:"number"`
  NumDec      float32  `form:"numDec"`
}
```

If you want to put your type into another package (tip: don't overdo the sub-packages), then it will need to become a `pkgname.Wish` as names are fully qualified.

**Added**

After a second look, you're also messing things up here:

```
 func Doall(Model string, Wish interface{}, Wish2 interface{}, Wishlist interface{}         ) {
     m := martini.Classic()
     fmt.Println ("martini.Classic =", m)
     m.Use(martini.Static("images")) // serve from the "images" directory as well
```

Your parameter list needs to provide a name for each type; you can't pass `Wish interface{}` as a parameter as `Wish` is a type, not a variable name.

You should either:

```
func DoAll(model string, wish interface{}, wish2 interface{}, wishList interface{}) { ... }
```

Or, better still, stop using `interface{}` like this and write:

```
func DoAll(model string, wishList []Wish, wishes... Wish) { ... }
```

However, your `DoAll` function does not seem to be referenced elsewhere, and is creating its own Martini instance. I highly suggest thinking about why things are "split out" like this if you're just starting out. Keep it simple - e.g.

```
func main() {
    m := martini.Classic()
    m.Use(martini.Static("images"))
    m.Use(DB())
    m.Use(render.Renderer(render.Options{...}))
    // No need for an anonymous function, which just adds clutter
    m.Get("/wishes/all", GetAllWishes)
    // Same goes for here
    m.Post("/wishes/new", PostWish)

    m.Run()
}
```

PS: I've fixed the formatting of your code, as it has a lot of unnecessary spacing before/after parenthesis. Make sure to use `gofmt`, which is included with the Go install and can be hooked into most popular editors.

Comment: Well, it looks like the only way get a type struct into a package is using the  "pkgname.Wish" you mentioned above. Thanks for the answer.